# Angular/Prime-NG/Visual Studio Code - <p-calendar> numberOfMonths doesn't work

Tags: html, angular, console, primeng

I've been struggling with the isue making a calendar using ng-prime tools.
My calendar has to show 3 months at the same time.

**ng-prime says on their site I need to use this code:**

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <h3>Multiple Months</h3>
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date11" [numberOfMonths]="3"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

**This is my code:**

```
<div class="G4_9_3 ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dates" dateFormat="DD/MM/yy" inline="true" [numberOfMonths]="3" selectionMode="multiple" [readonlyInput]="true" class="calCSS"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

The classes are only for CSS purposes. When I use NG serve on my project it won't open. I'm getting a error msg in console:
[Click to see error msg in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTgw5.png)

I have imported the module:

```
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';
```

And when I remove: `[numberOfMonths]="3"` my projects opens.

I've tried to understand what this means but I failed to do so.. Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks :)

Comment: have you import calendar module ?

Comment: import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar'; this module? If so, yes

Comment: I think the problem is the version of primeng you are using it works in version 6.1.4. what is your current version of primeng ?

Comment: It worked updating to newest version thanks :)